# Environment figure undefined

Tags: floats, environments, undefined

I am using latex to write a letter, but when I tried to insert a picture into the letter, latex it said that the figure environment undefined. I have already imported corresponding packages:

```
\documentclass{letter}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\addtolength{\voffset}{-0.5in}
\addtolength{\hoffset}{-0.3in}
\addtolength{\textheight}{2cm}
```

and I applied a basic way to insert a picture:

```
\begin{figure}[H]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.7\textwidth]{2-1-prev.png}
\end{figure}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Document class `letter` doesn't support floats. Do you have special reason to use it? Instead `\begin{figure}[H] \centering \includegraphics[width=0.7\textwidth]{2-1-prev.png} \end{figure}` rather use `\begin{center} \includegraphics[width=0.7\textwidth]{2-1-prev.png} \end{center}` or use `article` instead of `letter`.

Comment: Thanks! The document class is required, so I am now using minipage environment to insert pictures. However,  as ```\caption``` can only used in float environment, it is another problem to assign titles to pictures...

Comment: Load `caption` or `capt-of` package and than use `\captionof{figure}{ <caption text> }` (or  `\captionof{table}{ <caption text> }`. BTW, `letter` document class is intended for writing letters, not articles ...

Comment: Roger that, sir. Actually, I was required to write a letter, so this is the case. Thanks again for your help, have a nice day~

Comment: BTW, `subfigure` is obsolete package, instead it use `subfig` or `subcaption`. Both have different syntax for including sub images or table. IMPORTANT: both doesn't work outside of floats (figure, table).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be very unusual to have numbered floating figures in a letter (such a document could be made with `article` class even if you put it in the post and post it as a letter). So the expected usage for the `letter` class is

[image]

```
\documentclass{letter}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\begin{document}

\begin{letter}{Some Address\\Some Street\\Some City}

\opening{Dear sir,}

Zzzz zzz.

\begin{center}
  \includegraphics{example-image}
\end{center}


\end{letter}

\end{document}
```

However if you want to add a `figure` environment to `letter` class you can easily add it with the `float` package (or copy the `figure` code from `article`)

[image]

```
\documentclass{letter}
\usepackage{graphicx,float}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\newfloat{figure}{htbp}{lof}
\newlength\abovecaptionskip
\setlength\abovecaptionskip{10pt}
\floatname{figure}{Figure}

\begin{document}

\begin{letter}{Some Address\\Some Street\\Some City}

\opening{Dear sir,}

Zzzz zzz.

\begin{figure}
  \includegraphics{example-image}
\caption{a floating figure}
\end{figure}


\end{letter}

\end{document}
```